# Is there a shared cache directory that does not require WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

It is possible to trigger an apk installation with an intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(filename), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This does not work with `content://` URIs *("No activity found to handle Intent")* and the only other URI type I know of are `file://` URIs.

I tried to put the file in `getCacheDir()` but it seems the installer app does not have access to my app's cache dir.

It works with `getExternalCacheDir()`, but it requires the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` ("modify or delete the contents of your SD card") permission.

Since my app would normally not need that permission, I wonder if there is any cache directory that I can put the file in that does not require that permission but still allows the installer app to read the file?

Comment: Use getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: @greenapps Before Kitkat that seems to require WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.